# Proof by induction including fibonacci numbers

Tags: real-analysis, fibonacci-numbers

Let $p_1,p_2,p_3,...$ be fibonacci numbers. Prove by induction that

$p_n≥(\sqrt{2})^{n-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $n≥3$

Here is what I've tried:

Basic step: $p_3≥(\sqrt{2})^{3-1}=2≥2$

Assume $p_n≥(\sqrt{2})^{n-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $n≥3$ is true.

I now need to show that

$p_{n+1}≥(\sqrt{2})^{n}$

$p_{n+1}=p_n+p_{n-1}$

so we have

$p_n+p_{n-1}≥(\sqrt{2})^{n}$

which is the same as

$p_n+p_{n-1}≥2^{\frac{n}{2}}$

We then use the assumption of $p_n$

$p_n+p_{n-1}≥2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}+2^{\frac{n-2}{2}}$

I've been trying to work out where to go from here, but I am stuck.

Comment: So $p_{n+1}/2^{(n+1)/2}\ge 1/\sqrt2+1/2$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $p_n\geqslant\sqrt2^{n-1}$ and $p_{n-1}\geqslant\sqrt2^{n-2}$,\begin{align}p_{n+1}&=p_n+p_{n-1}\\&\geqslant\sqrt2^{n-1}+\sqrt2^{n-2}\\&=(\sqrt2+1)\sqrt2^{n-2}\end{align}and you want this to be greater than or equal to $\sqrt2^n$. But$$(\sqrt2+1)\sqrt2^{n-2}\geqslant\sqrt2^n\iff\sqrt2+1\geqslant\sqrt2^2=2$$and it is indeed true that $\sqrt2+1\geqslant2$.

Comment: I understand the first part (the algebra/rewriting). I don't understand why or how $(\sqrt2+1)\sqrt2^{n-2}=\sqrt(2)+1$. Can you give a hint or explain further?

Comment: @prucho12 I did *not* write that. What I wrote was that$$(\sqrt2+1)\sqrt2^{n-2}\iff\sqrt2+1\geqslant\sqrt2^2,$$which I got dividing both sides by $\sqrt2^{n-2}$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much